# about the fraction of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

In chapter 6 of Undergraduate commutative algebra, there is a question asking when given a ring $A$ and  a fixed multiplicative set $S$,there is a maximal multiplicative set $T$ such that $T^{-1}A=S^{-1}A$, where $T=${$t\in A| at \in S$ for some $a \in A$}.
I can understand why $T^{-1}A=S^{-1}A$,but how to prove that T is the maximal multiplicative set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend the multiplicative set $S$ to some larger set $U$, all elements in $U$ are invertible in $U^{-1}A$.  The subset $T$ is the set of all elements in $A$ which are invertible in $S^{-1}A$, so you cannot extend beyond $T$ without introducing additional invertible elements (hence the localizations wouldn't be equal anymore.)